# Render spinner with array values---React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, spinner

I'm trying to render spinner with values from array `this.state.stAccounts` which has the values `["00123-123124-1244","23234-24234-23234"]`.

assigning from Asyncstorage to state

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    stAccounts: [],
  }
}

async componentWillMount() {
  var accounts = await AsyncStorage.getItem('UserAccNos');
  if (accounts != "") {
    this.setState({ stAccounts: accounts });
    //  console.log(this.state.stAccounts + "are accounts");
  }
}

<Picker mode="dropdown" selectedValue={this.state.stAccountPicked}>
  {Object.keys(this.state.stAccounts).map((item, index) => { return (
    <Picker.Item label={item} value={index} key={index} />) }
  )}
</Picker>
```

Its rendering spinner. when I pick particular item. its not rendering picker as picked item in view  Please suggest good style with dropdown for spinner and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If stAccounts is an array, don't use `Object.keys`. Also, `Picker.Item` instead of `Item`.

Comment: updated question. can you check.

Comment: calling `setState` in `componentWillMount` may be the problem. It doesn't trigger a re-render since the component isn't mounted yet. Try changing it to `componentDidMount` instead.